# Calculate surface area of a sphere using the surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, surface-integrals

Given a sphere with:
$$F := \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1, x\le0\}$$
$$
\Rightarrow r = 1, \varphi = [\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}], \theta = [0, \pi]
$$

My Task is to calculate the surface area by using surface integral.

The default sphere paramterization:
$$
X\left(\varphi,\theta\right)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \varphi\sin \theta\\
\sin \varphi\sin \theta\\
\cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And it's derivates:
$$
X_{\varphi} \times X_{\theta} =
\begin{pmatrix}
-\sin \varphi\sin\theta\\
\cos \varphi\sin\theta\\
0
\end{pmatrix} \
\
\times \
\
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \varphi\cos\theta\\
\sin \varphi\cos\theta\\
-\sin\theta
\end{pmatrix}\
= \begin{pmatrix}
-\cos\varphi\sin^2\theta\\
-\sin\varphi\sin^2\theta\\
-\sin\theta\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}$$

The euclidean norm:
$$
\|
\begin{pmatrix}
-\cos\varphi\sin^2\theta\\
-\sin\varphi\sin^2\theta\\
-\sin\theta\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\|
= \sin^2\theta
$$

$$S(F)=\int_0^{\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\sin^2\theta \; d\varphi d\theta = \frac{\pi^2}{2}$$

Now my question is, where did I make a mistake? Since the surface should the surface of half a sphere, being $1/2 * 4\pi * 1^2 = 2\pi$

Comment: Shouldn't write $X(u,y)$ when you do not use $u,v$ (that's not an answer).

Comment: I get the norm to be $\lvert \sin \theta\rvert$ and not $\sin^2\theta$.

Comment: @ronno yeah you are right, and since $\theta$'s range is $[0, \pi]$ we can even omit the absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your euclidean norm is wrong, you most likely forgot about the square root. It should be:

$$
\left\|
\begin{pmatrix}
-\cos\varphi\sin^2\theta\\
-\sin\varphi\sin^2\theta\\
-\sin\theta\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\right\|
= \sqrt{(\cos^2\varphi+\sin^2\varphi)\sin^4\theta + \sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta} = \sqrt{(\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta)\sin^2\theta} = \sqrt{\sin^2\theta} = \sin\theta$$

And the integral:

$$S(F)= \left(\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}d\varphi\right) \cdot \left( \int_0^{\pi} \sin\theta d\theta\right) = \pi \cdot 2 = 2\pi$$

By the way, writing an independent variable as the innermost integral and with such weird boundaries is really bad style and confusing for the reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's weird though, we are told to use this notation since it's clearer according to our professor.